# Squared sum series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My goal is to find the sum

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[(1-\alpha)a^i + \alpha b^i \right]^2$$

Where 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 a &= 1 + \frac{\mu}{2} + \sqrt{( 1+\frac{\mu}{2} )^{2} - 1} \\
 b &= 1 + \frac{\mu}{2} - \sqrt{( 1+\frac{\mu}{2} )^{2} - 1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
(these are actually roots of a quadratic), $\mu>1$, and

$$\alpha = \frac{a^{n-1} - \mu a^{n}}{a^{n-1} - \mu a^{n} - b^{n-1} + \mu b^{n}}$$

I get that $a>1$ and $0<b<1$.

I verified numerically that the sequence corresponding to the sum converges to some number.

Also numerically it appears that $\alpha$ converges to $1$. Why does $\left( \frac{a^{n-1} - \mu a^{n}}{a^{n-1} - \mu a^{n} - b^{n-1} + \mu b^{n} }\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} \to 1$ ?

Assuming this $\alpha=1$ as $n \to \infty$, I could say that the terms with $a^i$ vanish to $0$ and I deal with a geometric series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b^{2i}=\frac{b^2}{1-b^2}$, but this doesn't seem correct (different limit when checking numerically. edit: it's correct after all).

My other approach was expanding the square and dealing with the sums separately, but this didn't go well either.

Comment: Since $\alpha$ depends on $n$, are you considering the series for each fixed $n$?

Comment: Ah you made me realize that this dependency makes the series troublesome.. Well, I would be glad to get to the solution considering a finite sum, i.e. fixing a single $n$. I thought that letting $n \to \infty$ makes this problem easier..

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you would like to know the $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^n [(1 - \alpha )a^i + \alpha b^i]^2$?

Comment: Yes that is what I stated in the beginning, the limit you gave would be equivalent to the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[(1-\alpha)a^i + \alpha b^i \right]^2$ right? As the sum of a series amounts to the limit of the sequence of partial sums. Otherwise, maybe there is a neat way to express it without a limit, i.e. to rewrite the finite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[(1-\alpha)a^i + \alpha b^i \right]^2$ in a way without a sum, using some algebraic identities.. that would be helpful too

Comment: I think that my original confusion was that the definition of $n$ is the same one which is suppsed in the definition of the infinite sum but I think it's clear now. I have calculated the partial sums and found the limit of them to be $b^2 / (1 - b^2)$, which as you said is not numerically justified. I'll write down my workings out in an answer and maybe someone will see the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we show that $\alpha \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{a^{n-1}(1 - \mu a)}{a^{n-1}(1 - \mu a) -b^{n-1}(1-\mu b) } \\
&= 1- \frac{b^{n-1}(1 - \mu b)}{a^{n-1}(1 - \mu a) -b^{n-1}(1-\mu b) }
\end{align}
which tends to $1$ because the denominator grows since $a > 1$ and the numerator goes to $0$ since $0 < b < 1$. Also note the rate of convergence is exponential, so the ratio test can show that for any polynomial $f(n)$ we have $(1-\alpha)f(n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Next let's consider the sum. Note that since $a, b$ are roots of the quadratic equation $x^2 - (2 + \mu)x + 1$ we get that $ab = 1$. Also we assume $a > 1$ and $0 < b < 1$. Let us calculate the $n$'th partial sum. 
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n [(1-\alpha)a^i + \alpha b^i]^2 \\
= &\sum_{i=1}^n (1-\alpha)^2a^{2i} + \alpha^2 b^{2i} + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)(ab)^i \\
= &(1-\alpha)^2 \sum_{i=1}^n a^{2i} + \alpha^2 \sum_{i=1}^n b^{2i} + 2\alpha(1-\alpha) \sum_{i=1}^n(ab)^i \\
= &(1-\alpha)^2a^2\frac{1-a^{2n}}{1-a^2} + \alpha^2 b^2 \frac{1 - b^{2n}}{1 - b^2} + 2\alpha(1 - \alpha)n
\end{align}

As $n \rightarrow \infty$ we see that the second term converges to $b^2 / (1 - b^2)$ and the right most term tends to zero since $(1 - \alpha)n$ tends to zero. It remains to consider the first term. Note that $(1 - \alpha)$ tends to zero but $(1 - a^{2n})$ tends to $-\infty $ so we need to take care.

\begin{align}
(1-\alpha)^2a^2\frac{1-a^{2n}}{1-a^2} &= (1-\alpha) a^2 \frac{1}{1- a^2} -\left( \frac{b^{n-1}(1 - \mu b)}{a^{n-1}(1 - \mu a) -b^{n-1}(1-\mu b) } \right)^2 a^2 \frac{a^{2n}}{1 - a^2}\\
&= (1-\alpha) a^2 \frac{1}{1- a^2} -\left( \frac{b^{n-1}(1 - \mu b)a^n}{a^{n-1}(1 - \mu a) -b^{n-1}(1-\mu b) } \right)^2 a^2 \frac{1}{1 - a^2} \\
&= (1-\alpha) a^2 \frac{1}{1- a^2} - b^{-1}\left( \frac{(ab)^n(1 - \mu b)}{a^{n-1}(1 - \mu a) -b^{n-1}(1-\mu b) } \right)^2 a^2 \frac{1}{1 - a^2} \\
\end{align}
Since $ab = 1$ the numerator of the large fraction is constant and since $a > 1$ its denominator grows. So this whole expression tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity.

Going back to the partial sum, the only term which does not tend to zero tends to $b^2 / (1 - b^2)$.

Comment: the problem is that your quadratic is wrong and $ab=1$ as one can see by doing the multiplication directly

Comment: Thank you for spotting this, I have editted the solution with the correct polynomial. However this does not appear to change the overall concluson which is wrong according to OP's numerical calculation

Comment: $\alpha$ depends on $i$ in each summation term (at least in the original infinite sum) so your computation is for a different sum (one that you fix $\alpha$ for a given $n$ get a term $s_n$ and look at its limit with $n$) so no wonder your result which looks right btw is different -the OP notation is just bad as this discussion shows

Comment: @Conrad How come $\alpha$ depends on $i$? Its definitions says the dependence is only $n$ (and $\mu$), so by fixing $n$ in the beginning, we fix $\alpha$ and it won't change during the iterations.

Comment: @OliverClarke you are right in your calculations! I'm so sorry for the confusion, I mistakenly ran the experiment for the $n$ which wasn't large enough to get the behaviour as with $n \to \infty$... Indeed $\frac{b^2}{1-b^2}$ comes out as the limit. Overall your answer is great, thanks!